# How can I use jsonapi in Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, json-api, moshi

I need use [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/) in retrofit2. I try with [moshi-jsonapi](https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi/) but I can't use moshi ConverterFactory.

TokenModel.java

```
@JsonApi(type = "tokens")
public class TokenModel extends Resource {
    @Json(name = "cell_phone")
    public String cellPhone;
}
```

TestService.java:

```
public interface TestService {
    @POST("token")
    Call<TokenModel> newOtp(@Body TokenModel tokenModel);
}
```

TestProvider.java:

```
public class TestProvider {
    private TestService testService;

    public TestProvider() {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Retrofit refRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ClientConfigs.BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
//                .addConverterFactory(????????????????????????????)
                .build();
        testService = refRetrofit.create(TestService.class);
    }

    publicTestService getTestService() {
        return testService;
    }
}
```

If I use `MoshiConverterFactory` make error `Unable to create converter for class com.xxx.xxx.model.TokenModel`!

Use Retrofit:

```
TsetProvider testProvider = new TestProvider();
TestService testService = testProvider.getTestService();

TokenModel tokenModel = new TokenModel();
tokenModel.cellPhone = "121212129999";

Call<TokenModel> call = testService.newOtp(tokenModel);
call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TokenModel> call, Response<TokenModel> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TokenModel> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [moshi-jsonapi](https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi) documentation you need to add the libraries factory to the moshi instance:

```
// First create the factory
JsonAdapter.Factory jsonApiAdapterFactory = ResourceAdapterFactory.builder()
  .add(TokenModel.class)
  .build();

// Create a custom moshi instacne
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
  .add(jsonApiAdapterFactory)
  .build();

// Add the custom moshi instance to Retrofits Converter Factory
Retrofit refRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(ClientConfigs.BASE_URL)
  .client(httpClient)
  .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
  .build();
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. It's resolved with your code.

And I find other [solution](https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi/issues/30) same your answer.